# How to root Samsung galaxy chat B5330?

Tags: rooting, samsung-galaxy-chat

The title says it all. I have read [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/rooting/info) rooting tag info throughly and did all that was necessary to ensure this question is not duplicate.

There are some guides on the web, but they only make me go mad as each has some issue (broken links, poor comments, etc). So if anyone can give trustworthy answers, please do.

> Note: The OS for galaxy chat has been updated a while ago. Now, it has jelly bean.

---

After checking all the generic methods,I've found only two methods that could possibly root galaxy chat.out of them ready to root has very bad rating

---

The second method is **Bin4ry method**.But there is no way one could understand if it's actually rooting or not(the app says,it will either show message on completion or show nothing). If anyone succeeds using bin4ry method.Do add the approx required time.

Comment: Correct – well done :) I've just linked to your question from our [rooting index](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/1184/16575). Until someone can answer your question, you might wish to consult that index for "generic methods" which might apply.

Comment: Any luck since then?

Answer (score 1):

I. Before You Begin:

1. Rooting voids the warranty of your device (until you unroot it).
2. Please charge your device to have at least 60% of battery life
3. download Root Package from http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1936878
4. Download and place the Root Package file onto your Desktop. Do NOT extract it.
5. Connect your device to your PC using the USB cable.
6. Copy the Root Package file over to the SD card of your device.
7. Once done, disconnect the device from your PC.
8. Turn OFF the device.
9. Reboot the device into Stock Recovery. To do so, press and hold the Volume DOWN+Home+Power buttons together.
10. Once inside the recovery, choose apply update from sdcard.
11. Select the Root Package(update.zip) you copied earlier to the device.
12. Be patient and let it root the device.
13. Once done, reboot the device.
14. You’re good to go!

Brilliant! You now have root access on your Galaxy Chat B5330 device

Comment: sorry  for late reply, but (1). The file is for android 4.0.4 but I have upgraded to 4.1.2 (2). Anyway it doesn't work.Please have a look at my two new posts [on xda-devel](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=51278686#post51278686) and [on AE](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/66033/51292) .Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're running an OS between 4.0 and 4.3,you can just use VROOT to do it.

Comment: Thanks for replying, can you provide more info?

Comment: Well, VROOT is a Chinese tool for rooting Android devices, i have tested on 4.0.x 4.1.x 4.2.x, you just install ADB drivers for your device and then run VROOT, it works automatically.