# Options darked in JOdin3 Casual

Tags: rooting, odin

I am trying to root my phone using JOdin3(as Odin does not work on Linux).

But some options are darked out as shown in the image below.
[image]

I need to select Auto reboot and F reset time for continuing.What should I do?

Also my phone goes into charging mode(shows the green charging bar) quickly after going into odin mode, so I'm unable to do anything.

<sup>I had to use `Odin` tag because there is no `JOdin` tag.Please change it if you think it would be appropriate</sup>

Comment: (1) what about if you click the reset button? (2) what if you set a file (e.g. pda, or phone)? Does it enable the checkboxes?

Comment: @geffchang No it does not enable checkboxes in both cases.I also tried "install drive..." button but it also didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the developer, those disabled checkboxes are not implemented. [Source](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=51400190&postcount=104).

You can still proceed with the flash even if `F. Reset Time` is disabled / unchecked. There should be no problems with it.